# Why same output for both the cases?

Tags: javascript

I created two different variables a and b and in first for loop, I  placed a.push and then a.unshift and in second for loop, I placed b.unshift first and then b.push but why the both variables (a and b) output will be same as [10,  9,  8,  7,  6,  5,  4, 3,  2,  1,  0,  0,  1,  2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8, 9, 10]

```
let a =  [];
for(let i=0 ; i <=10 ; i++) {
    a.push(i); 
    a.unshift(i);
}
console.log(a); 

let b =  [];
for(let j=0 ; j <=10 ; j++) {
    b.unshift(j); 
    b.push(j); 
}
console.log(b);
```

Comment: What difference were you expecting?

Comment: I think in the first case  the result would be [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] and in the second case the result would be [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 ]

Comment: Switching the order of 'push' and 'unshift' has no effect. Unshift adds the item to front of the array, and unshift, to the back, so in both cases you're building the array "from the middle out". To get '[0, 1, 2...", you would change your for loop to 'for (let j=10; j >=0; j--'.

Comment: ya, its working thanks @zanerock

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and returns the new length of the array.
>
> The unshift() method adds one or more elements to the beginning of an array and returns the new length of the array.

First one always works on the end, second one on the beginning. So it doesn't matter if you call first `unshift()` or `push()` because they do the same action every time. It's like adding. It doesn't matter if you do 3 + 5 or 5 + 3. Theoretically, it do the same in the opposite order, but because it uses the same value the result is the same.

Try

```
let a =  [];
for(let i=0 ; i <=10 ; i++) {
    a.push(i + 1); 
    a.unshift(i);
}
console.log(a); 

let b =  [];
for(let j=0 ; j <=10 ; j++) {
    b.unshift(j + 1); 
    b.push(j); 
}
console.log(b);
```

The result is different.